# "A letter is written to inform" vs "A letter is written to be informed"

Tags: grammar, british-english, passive-voice, infinitives, present-tense

**I write a letter to inform him**

I want to convert this sentence into the passive voice. But then wrote down these three sentences. I can't understand the difference between these sentences. Can anyone explain the difference?

1. *A letter is written to be informed him.*
2. *I write a letter to be informed him.*
3. *A letter is written to inform him*

Comment: 1 and 2 are meaningless. 3 is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both versions using "to be informed" are incorrect. The reason is that the "to be" form refers back to the noun phrase *before* "to be" so the object of the verb (he in this case) would have to be placed *before* the "to be" phrase. For instance:

"He was to be informed by a letter from me"

Also the accusative form of the third person pronoun (him) is used for objects of verbs (for instance "I sent a letter to him") but in the passive voice as you have constructed it "he" is the subject so the pronoun must take the nominative form.

You can create a passive sentence with "him" as the object but then the subject has to be "the letter". You have done this in your third sentence which is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The first two are grammatically incorrect.  The third sounds fairly natural and carries the meaning you intend.